# My load more function is working on button click, but it doesn't work on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

The code below works on `ng-click` of a button:

```
$scope.loadMore = function() {
    var container = $('ul.notification-popup-scroll');                
    $scope.totalDisplayed += 4;
    $scope.notifications = notifications.data.notification;
});
```

However if I try to do something like this, the scope variable has no effect.

```
$('ul.notification-popup-scroll').scroll(function() {
    var container = $('ul.notification-popup-scroll');
    if (container.scrollTop() > 500) {
        $scope.totalDisplayed += 4;
        $scope.notifications = notifications.data.notification;
    }
});
```

I am trying to get infinite scrolling to work, but I just want to load data from an already fetched object. I am not doing a http request each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.totalDisplayed += 4;
    $scope.notifications = notifications.data.notification;
});
```

`$scope.$apply` tells angular that something has changed.

Comment: My IDE says that $apply is an unresolved function name :-( Can I try $scope.apply?

Comment: OK This worked, but I just realized I am checking if scrollTop is > 500 every time. How do I load more when the scroll bar comes to the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

Use [angular-inview](https://github.com/thenikso/angular-inview) directive.

I think it's a best solution for you:

```
<body in-view-container>

   <!-- your items rendered here -->

   <div in-view="$inview && loadMore()"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried to read about inview, but couldn't understand how that works in my context. Could you explain in to me in a beginner's term?

Comment: Very simple, include 'angular-inview' module in your app and add 'in-view-container' to body tag (or your scrollable container), that's it.